# How to filter and sort nested objects? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, filter

Data sample:

```
   const people = [
         1:{
           id : 1,
           name: 'James',
           age: 31,
           toBeDeleted: false,
           position: 2
         },
         2:{
           id : 2,
           name: 'John',
           age: 45,
           toBeDeleted: true,
           position: 3
         },
         3:{
           id : 3,
           name: 'Paul',
           age: 65,
           toBeDeleted: false,
           position: 1
         }
       ];
```

I try this way, but it doesn't work :

```
   const sorted = Object.values(people)
       .filter((people) => people.toBeDeleted !== true)
       .sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position);
```

If I delete the id keys, then my code works.

In result must be array like this :

```
   const people = [
         {
           id : 3,
           name: 'Paul',
           age: 65,
           toBeDeleted: false,
           position: 1
         },
         {
           id : 1,
           name: 'James',
           age: 31,
           toBeDeleted: false,
           position: 2
         }
       ];
```

the id keys are used in the project to select the necessary records, so I can't delete them

Comment: I'm not sure I see any reason for the ReactJS tag to be included on this... looks like it is all dealing with plain JS...

Comment: Your data sample doesn't look like a valid javascript array

Comment: Your ids are already included in the (invalid, as @WebbH mentions) array objects. You can just use `arr.find(obj => obj.id)` to get an object from the array.

Comment: @AlexanderNied the problem is related to ReactJS

Comment: @AndreB Don't update your answer to the solution. It makes the question/answer confusing to future readers.

Comment: @BrianThompson OK. I returned it as it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the people variable. From '[,]' to '{,}'.

```js
const people = {
     1:{
       id : 1,
       name: 'James',
       age: 31,
       toBeDeleted: false,
       position: 2
     },
     2:{
       id : 2,
       name: 'John',
       age: 45,
       toBeDeleted: true,
       position: 3
     },
     3:{
       id : 3,
       name: 'Paul',
       age: 65,
       toBeDeleted: false,
       position: 1
     }
};

const sorted = Object.values(people)
       .filter((people) => people.toBeDeleted !== true)
       .sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position);
console.log(sorted);
```